# Android translucent status bar but non-translucent navigation bar (if present)

Tags: android, navigationbar, layerdrawable

I'm trying to create splash screen for android application with this article: [Splash Screens the Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/). As article says, I created LayerDrawable with two layers: background bitmap and logo (also bitmap). Logo need to be located at the bottom of screen with indent 32dp, for example. Here my drawable:

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_image" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:bottom="@dimen/margin_splash">

    <bitmap
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_green" />
</item>
```

I pointed this drawable as `android:windowBackground` param in my splash activity theme. I also want to have transparent status bar when splash screen is shown on devices where this feature is supported (API >=19), so I created two resource files for different android versions and in values-v19\styles.xml I pointed flag `android:windowTranslucentStatus` as true. Here my `values/styles.xml` and `values-v19/styles.xml`:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and
**values-v19/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But on some Android devices with Soft NavigationBar my logo is overlapped by it.
[image: Logo overlapping by NavigationBar]
I tried to point `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` flag as false but without success.

Is any way to make Android Soft NavigationBar transparent together with 
transparent status bar, or I need detect Soft NavigationBar availability in onCreate method of my splash activity and update my LayerDrawable by adding bottom indent for logo to the height of NavigationBar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item> <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

Also you can a little bottom padding to your bitmap item in the layer drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved this problem by setting the following attributes.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

This attributes is set to values-v21 directory.